# Agent is disconnected but TeamCity server showing connected

Tags: teamcity

I am was having my agent connected to server. By some reason console got close and connected got dropped. Now server shows agent connected but it is not. When I try to connect the agent it says agent with same name is already connected.
I unauthorized the previous agent and disable also. But it is not helping me.
Can anyone suggest me something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server displays an agent as connected, then most probably there is an agent that IS connected. Also, "agent with same name is already registered" message confirms this.

You can check that you have no TeamCity agents running (i.e. check for java processes) or just reboot the agent computer. If that does not help, try looking through the logs and getting details from the agent registration messages - they list IP and port that agents are coming from.